# TP-Link Archer T2U wifi is not working

Tags: drivers, 18.10, ralink, tp-link

Still no luck to install the driver for TP-LINK Archer T2U on fresh installed Ubuntu 18.10. I checked and tried all other posts in here, but I had no luck.

The installation process was like this:

```
# sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0
# sudo dkms add -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
# sudo dkms build -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
# sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

After rebooting there was  still no Wi-Fi:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Answer (score 0):

Several different chipsets have been used in that product line, so it's possible you aren't installing the correct one. The [WikiDevi page for Archer T2U](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U) indicates that it's most likely a Mediatek driver that you'll need, not the Realtek one you installed. I've avoided buying these because some chipsets are easier to get working than others, and you can't be sure which one you'll get when you buy them online.

Comment: the method I`m using is as follow: #git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
#cd mt7610u
#make
#sudo cp firmware/*  /lib/firmware
#sudo insmod mt7610u.ko ---- but on the last step to insmod the mt7610u.ko file it says: insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mt7610u.ko: Unknown symbol in module , but the file is there, can you help please ?

Comment: I just came across a question where the user had the same issue. Try the steps suggested there: https://askubuntu.com/a/1106753/577936