# TP-Link Archer T2U Plus usb wi-fi dongle is not working on Kubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, kubuntu

I bought a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus usb wi-fi dongle. I cannot get it to work on Kubuntu 20.04.4.
What I tried so far:
Open the terminal and execute the following commands :

1. Update the package information :

`sudo apt update`

2. Install dkms and git :

`sudo apt install dkms git`

3. Install Build Dependencies :

`sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

4. Download the Driver files using git :

`git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

5. Navigate to the Downloaded directory :

`cd rtl8812au`

6. Install the Driver

`sudo make dkms_install`

This info came from https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/184118. It didn't change the situation though. Still not working/no light on the dongle.
Got info from https://deviwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U_Plus and downloaded the driver 5.3.4 from a link. The usb-id was the same. So now I have got a tar.gz file. I unpacked this. I have no idea how to install this driver. Content of the folder see picture.[image: content unpakked tar.gz]. 
I have got this in hardinfo:product unindentified and class unknown. And 'can't open device' error in Konsole. See image.[image: hardinfo tp-link Archer T2U]
I really need a stronger wi-fi connection than my build in one on my HP Envy. Can anybody save the day, so to say. 
`lsmod` shows me module r8169 ( size 77824, used by 0 )and a realtek module ( size 32768, used by 1 )
Edit 220618
`lsusb` shows me `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter` ( amongst others )..Systeminfo:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-51-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
In triple boot with Mint 20.3 Una and Windows 10.
The device works in Windows 10, but I really hate Windows ( need it for work ) and it is not my private daily driver. Will provide any info asked for.
Looked at [TP-Link Archer T2U wifi is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104746/tp-link-archer-t2u-wifi-is-not-working) as well.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and, as always, when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must.

Comment: Both are off. System works fine, except that TP-Link ( and the unsupported Fingerprint-reader ) don't work. Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: You need https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you so much. It is working. If you make this an answer I can accept it and upvote it.

Comment: (Off-topic but informative) I booted into my Mint 20.3, installed the driver and it is working there as well. Thanks again Jeremy31.