# TP-Link Archer T2U Plus usb wi-fi dongle not working after kernel update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, kernel, kubuntu

After a kernel update ( to 5.13.0-52-generic ) my TP Link Archer T2U Wifi dongle doesn't work anymore. This is related to my question [TP-Link Archer T2U Plus usb wi-fi dongle is not working on Kubuntu 20.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414551/tp-link-archer-t2u-plus-usb-wi-fi-dongle-is-not-working-on-kubuntu-20-04-4). After using the provided link by Jeremy31 I got it working in Kubuntu 20.04.4. with kernel 5.13.0-51-generic
When I do this

```
patrick@Lappy:~/rtl8812au$ sudo make dkms-install
make: *** No rule to make target 'dkms-install'.  Stop.
```

It doesn't work. Do I have to delete everything first, and do this again?
Open the terminal and execute the following commands :

Update the package information :

```
sudo apt update
```

Install dkms and git :

```
sudo apt install dkms git
```

Install Build Dependencies :

```
sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Download the Driver files using git :

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708
```

Navigate to the Downloaded directory :

```
cd rtl8812au
```

Install the Driver

```
sudo make dkms_install
```

Or am I missing something else/have to do something else? If a new kernel does not copy the module it is pretty stupid. 
Related but not supported on this site, so for information only: In `mint 20.3` I have the same problem after a kernel update.
Systeminfo:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
In triple boot with Mint 20.3 Una and Windows 10.
The device works in Windows 10, but I really hate Windows ( need it for work ) and it is not my private daily driver. Will provide any info asked for. 
I tried:
patrick@Lappy:~$ apt list upgadable 
Bezig met oplijsten... Klaar
patrick@Lappy:~$ cd rtl8812au 
patrick@Lappy:~/rtl8812au$ sudo
install-driver.sh 
sudo: install-driver.sh: command not found
patrick@Lappy:~/rtl8812au$ sudo make /install-driver.sh 
[sudo]
password for patrick:  
make: *** No rule to make target
'/install-driver.sh'.  Stop. 
    patrick@Lappy:~/rtl8812au$ sudo
./install-driver.sh 
    sudo: ./install-driver.sh: command not found
So I clearly am missing something.

Comment: Are you sure you've applied all security fixes?  Ubuntu 20.04.4 is now (*fully upgraded with 20.04.5 changes from jammy now filtering thru*) using the 5.15 kernel with HWE and the 5.13 kernel just days away from EOL.

Comment: Looks like a change was made to the scripts and now `sudo ./install-driver.sh` is needed rather than dkms-install

Comment: @guiverc I update every day. I only have the .deb version ( a0.23 ) of 0AD on hold ( because of the mods and I have 0.25 as snap ). If I do 'apt list upgradable' it gives me nothing.

Comment: @guiverc please see my edit. apt list upgradable gives me nothing.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I cannot get it to work properly. Can you help me a little bit further please.

Comment: `cd 8821au-20210708 && sudo ./install-driver.sh`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you so much. These commands worked. What I did was navigate to the file in Dolphin and then rightclick and choose open in Terminal. Then typed the 'sudo ./install-driver.sh' command which did not work. If you make this an answer I can accept and uǜote it.